AIC comes out of NA when conducting TSR
Does anyone have ideas why when running a TSR in R Iend up getting NA for AIC to checkmodel fit?
my comands looks like this.
model2 <- glm(cases ~ fourier + time,analysis_data,family=quasipoisson)
summary(model2)

part of the returns below.
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> (Dispersion parameter for quasipoisson family taken to be 5.207482)
>
> Null deviance: 20466.2  on 481  degrees of freedom
>
> Residual deviance:  2151.8  on 446  degrees of freedom
> AIC: NA
>
> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6


Marking this as a duplicate might be a little bit opaque. Because quasi-likelihood models do not technically have a likelihood, you can't technically compute an AIC. People have defined a "quasi-AIC" which is described in the linked question.
